# Where in the Android framework is the mouse pointer drawn?

Tags: android, graphics, mouse

I'm looking for the code in the Android framework that's responsible for drawing the mouse cursor (i.e. when a Bluetooth mouse is connected). Does anyone know where that is?

Answer (score 1):

[reference android 4.4 codebase]

For Mouse drawing, check doUpdateSprites() method in frameworks/base/services/input/SpriteController.cpp. This is the class which sets positions,size etc. If you you need support for Hardware mouse (USB mouse) you have add your HAL code to allocate/draw with framebuffer.

Regards,
Ravi Pandit

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would use the MotionEvent class ( [further explained here:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)) 
Then you could use the x and y coordinates to find where to place the image of a cursor.

Comment: Thanks -- that's how mouse events are received, but I want to know how the system renders the mouse cursor when a mouse is connected.

Comment: Couldn't you display an image that you have made of a mouse cursor according to the x and y coordinates on the screen? Then you could possibly scale it based on the screens density of pixels.

Comment: No -- that would only work for my application -- the mouse pointer would disappear when my application quits. Android is capable of rendering a mouse cursor over every application (e.g. as happens when a BT mouse is connected). I want to track down where that happens.

Comment: Oh, my apologies! I am very sorry that I misunderstood your question!